# How to search for a text string in a ppsx file?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a ppsx file.

I am unable to search for a text string in it.

Ctrl + F doesn't work, and neither does anything else that I have tried.

Comment: Do you open the PPSX file just by opening/double-click into a slideshow, or do you open it in PowerPoint to edit? If you simply don't know how to open it in PowerPoint to edit/search it, open PowerPoint first and then do File > Open and choose the PPSX file. Once open in the regular PowerPoint, you should be able to Ctrl+F (or select "Find" in the Home tab) and search for text

Comment: @YisroelTech Thank you. Could you please add it as an answer so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit (and therefore be able to use ***Find*** in it) a PPSX (PowerPoint Slideshow) you can first open the PowerPoint program, and from within the program open the file (File > Open and choose the PPSX file.)

Once it's open in the regular PowerPoint editing mode, you should be able to Ctrl+F (or select "Find" in the Home tab) and search for text.